# Why is the reason of using BJTs instead of diodes in Bandgap references?

Tags: diodes, bjt, voltage-reference

I'm just asking what is the main reason to use BJT transistors as pn or np junctions for bandgap voltage reference instead of using just pn or np diodes also available on CMOS technologies.

[image]

Comment: Ideality factor, primarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diode-connected BJTs behave more like ideal diodes than diodes. In particular the ideality factor \$\eta\$ is 1.0 rather than somewhere closer to 1.5 or 2 for diodes. The exact reasons for this are a bit involved. See [this](https://www.ece.umd.edu/class/enee480.F2005/DiodeIdeality.pdf) paper, for example.

Comment: @spehro-perfhany The link the paper is broken. Could you post a reference or doi?

Answer (score 2):

Although diodes are indeed available in all CMOS processes, their main use is for ESD protection. That means that modelling accuracy is less of a priority for these devices. That's one reason not to use these diodes.

I have jet to see a CMOS-only process where there is an NPN available. A component which often **is** available is a **Vertical PNP** and these are then often used as diodes in a bandgap circuit.

This vertical PNP is a "parasitic" component which you get "for free". It usually has a terrible beta but for use as a diode this does not matter.

I'm sure you could use an ESD diode as the basis for a bandgap but in the end the structure of the diode will be very similar to that Vertical PNP.

Also ESD diodes need to be large in order to cope with the current. For a vertical PNP there is no need to be large so it can be made much smaller.

In practice, in most process design kits you will only find ESD diodes in size large and larger while the PNP will be a more flexible device where you as a designer can determine its size (within limits of course).